# What's the difference between “quelqu'un” and “quelqu”?

Tags: pronoms, élision

I wanted to know differences between "quelqu'un" and "quelqu" and when to use which.
I have searched for it but because I am new to French couldn't find anything helpful about this.

Comment: I'd presumed *quelqu* was a typo and you meant *quelque* ... please edit if so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Quelqu* is the abbreviation of the indefinite adjective *quelque*. It is never used on its own. It is only<sup>1</sup> used in *quelqu'un* and *quelqu'une*, the contracted forms of *quelque un* and *quelque une* – contraction is mandatory here, you can never write or say *<s>quelque un</s>*.

*Quelqu'un* means "someone". "*Quelque un* = some one", if you will. It can either be used to designate some indeterminate person (*Il y a quelqu'un ?* = "Is someone there?"), or to designate a determined person (*C'est quelqu'un de bien* = "She/he is a good person", literally "This is someone good."). You cannot use *quelqu'une* for this, even if the person is feminine.

*Quelqu'un* and *quelqu'une* can be used to designate an indeterminate person among others. For example *Quelqu'une de ces personnes est coupable* = "Someone among these people is guilty".

---

<sup>1</sup> References: [Druide](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/que-jusque-lorsque-puisque-quoique-presque-quelque-qu%C3%A9lider), [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1745), [Reverso](http://grammaire.reverso.net/5_6_02_elision.shtml), [Études littéraires](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire/elision.php).

Comment: Not only in *quelqu'un(e)*. There is also: *quelqu'autre*, *quelqu'avantage*, *quelqu'interêt*, ...

Comment: @jlliagre Toutes les sources que je trouve précisent qu'il est interdit d'élider le e de quelque sauf dans quelqu'un et quelqu'une.

Comment: @jlliagre J’ai toujours orthographié ça quelque avantage, quelque intérêt.

Comment: Je ne fais pas non plus ces élisions mais elles ne me choquent pas et je pensais, à tort, qu'elles étaient acceptées. N'hésite pas à citer tes sources. On peut quand même noter que cette règle n'a pas toujours existé. On trouve quelques élisions dans la littérature: Diderot *Rien n'est plus faux que ces mises soient comme 2 à 1 ou dans quelqu'autre rapport que celui de 3 à 1* et aussi une fameuse dans la dictée de Mérimée: *Quelles que soient et **quelqu'exiguës** qu'aient pu paraître, à côté de la somme due, les arrhes qu'étaient censés avoir données la douairière et le marguillier...*

Comment: @jlliagre https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/que-jusque-lorsque-puisque-quoique-presque-quelque-qu%C3%A9lider http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1745 http://grammaire.reverso.net/5_6_02_elision.shtml http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire01b.htm https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire/elision.php

Comment: Il y a aussi les expressions de type "il fait 2 mètres et quelques", où "quelque" est utilisé seul

Comment: @Random "Quelque" peut bien sûr être utilisé seul, c'est un mot comme les autres. "Quelqu" (sans e) ne peut jamais être utilisé seul.

Answer (score 0):

*Quelqu'un* is “someone” or “some one [of a set of something, *usually* people].

*Quelque* (ou *quelques*) is just “some” or “several”, e.g. *depuis quelques années, j'ai voulu faire quelque chose de passionnant, mais je suis resté ennuyeusement ennuyeux*.

As noted elsewhere, ***quelqu*** seul (privé l'**e**) n'est jamais correct.

Comment: Can a real French speaker school me on whether *passionnel* and/or *passionnant* are correct here?

Comment: “Quelque chose **de** passionnant”. See [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de): [Après les pron. neutres indéf., interr., exclam. ou dém. quelqu'un, quelque chose, pas grand-chose, autre chose, qui, que, quoi, ce, ceci, cela, rien, tout.] «Rien de neuf?» demanda sa femme (Dabit, Hôtel,1929, p. 169). Je leur trouve à toutes [les femmes] quelque chose de joli (Triolet, Prem. accroc,1945, p. 9)

Comment: Je crois que ... alors, est-ce que *«de passionnant»* signifie que «je le fais hors de désir» plutôt que «je le fais parce que c'est excitant»?

Comment: I realise it's a very fine distinction to make

Comment: We don't have the turn "out of" in French. “La passion me pousse à faire qqch” is the closest I can come up with for now (Passion pushes me to do smthg, i.e. I do smthg out of passion *or* this smthg I do is passion-driven). “Je le fais hors de désir”, though not grammatically exactly  perfect, would be understood as “I do it, but it has nothing to do with desire”.

Comment: So if you do something that is stimulating and interesting, you do *quelque chose de passionnant*. Unfortunately, these simple little things are the hardest to explain and understand. It is to some extent similar to the difference between "I run" and "I am running" for a French person learning English: you have to know it, but very few people can explain the whys & hows simply...

Comment: Why do you write "as noted *in the comments* of the other answer*? It is noted clearly in my answer.

Comment: *Quelque chose de passionnel* would have been very different, often related to a passionate love, while *quelque chose de passionnant* is something exciting, thrilling and/or captivating, depending on what you are talking about. Note too that *ennuyeusement ennuyeux* is quite pleonastic but I have no doubt it was intended.

Comment: @Najib I see the comment is your own!

Comment: @jlliagre yes, I thought it was funny - sorry!

Comment: No reason to be sorry. That's a valid stylistic effect, not a boringly boring one :-)

Comment: This discussion looks like a question and answer to me :-)