# Adjectif après « quelques-uns »

Tags: grammaire, accord

J'ai rencontré la phrase suivante dans mon livre de grammaire française :

> Le professeur a donné des exercices à faire pour demain. Il y en a quelques-uns de très difficiles.

Considérons alors la phrase suivante :

> Il m'a posé des questions. Il y en a quelques-unes [intéressant].

Comment accorde-t-on dans ce cas ? Est-il correct de dire « quelques-unes d'intéressantes » ? Je sais qu'on n'accorde pas l'adjectif qui modifie « quelque chose », donc cela m'a vraiment troublé.

Merci d'avance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quelqu'un** comme **quelque chose** ne se rencontre qu'au masculin<sup>1</sup> :

> Cette œuvre, c'est **quelque chose** de **grand**. (mais "quelque **grande** chose")

> Cette femme, c'est **quelqu'un** de **grand**. (mais le très rare "**[Quelqu'une](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28707/whats-the-difference-between-quelquun-and-quelqu/28709#28709)** de ces personnes est coupable")

En revanche, ***quelques-uns*** s'accorde en genre :

> Il y en a **quelques-uns** de **grands**.

> Il y en a **quelques-unes** de **grandes**.

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>***Quelqu'une*** est présent dans les dictionnaires et on peut en trouver quelques occurrences dans des œuvres littéraires mais son usage en français contemporain est tellement rare (200 fois moins présent à l'écrit) qu'il risque d'être considéré comme fautif ou dit sur le mode de la plaisanterie. Il est cependant très possible que la situation soit en train de s'améliorer avec la tendance générale à la féminisation des noms jusque-là exclusivement ou essentiellement masculins. On voit sur Google Ngram que la décroissance de *quelqu'une* s'inverse à partir de 2008 environ.</sub>

[image]

Comment: Merci ! Ça me paraît un peu étrange que le nom « chose » est féminin tandis que « quelque chose » s'accorde comme pronom masculin ... Y a-t-il une explication (historique peut-être) pour ça ?

Comment: J'imagine que le fait que ce soit indéfini et neutre a entraîné le masculin puisqu'il n'y a pas de neutre en français. D'autres composés avec *chose* sont masculins (grand-chose, autre chose).

Comment: @jlliagre Antidote affirme que "quelqu'une" existe :) J'imagine qu'il s'agit de la nouvelle graphie.

Comment: [quelqu’une](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelqu%E2%80%99une) Wiktionaire

Comment: _Le pronom indéfini quelqu’un, formé à partir de quelque et un, a comme formes possibles : quelqu’un (masc. sing.), quelqu’une (fém. sing.), quelques-uns (masc. pl.) et quelques-unes (fém. pl.)._ [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3437)

Comment: @Oreste Oui, *quelqu'une* est rarissime mais "existe". Je l'ai déjà cité dans ma réponse.

Comment: What I mean in my reply, is despite *quelqu'une* exists and has some use cases, I have never heard (outside by very young kids) *Cette femme, c'est quelqu'une de grande*. Everyone understand what it means though.

Comment: Ni Antidote ni la BDL ne mentionnent pas que "quelqu'une" est rare. Peut-être que la féminisation de ce mot est plus courant au Québec ? Mais [BtB](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_q&page=9A0cx34B36H4.html) écrit en effet que c'est rare ou littéraire.

Answer (score 0):

Le mode grammatical *neutre*  est régi en français par le mode masculin, comme le pronom *on* dérive de *homme* = l'humain = l'espèce humaine, tandis que celle mâle se définit par *Les hommes* par contraste à **Les femmes*.

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question. De plus,il n'y a pas de *on* dans *quelqu'un*, il y a *un* qui a comme féminin *une*, comme *chacun* a comme féminin *chacune*. La question est légitime.