# « Quelqu'un » même si on parle d'une femme ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre

Dans *Jean de Florette*, le Papet veut qu'Ugolin prenne une femme, alors il propose de « trouver quelqu'un » :

[image: citation du livre]

> Mais il faut qu'une femme vienne ici de temps en temps. Je te trouverai quelqu'un.

Est-ce vraiment le cas qu'on utilise le masculin / le neutre même s'il s'agit clairement d'une femme ? Si c'est le cas, quand donc est-ce qu'on dirait plutôt *quelqu'une* ?

Comment: Voir aussi https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44731/adjectif-apr%c3%a8s-quelques-uns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...]
> *Quelqu’un* est aussi utilisé comme nominal, en emploi absolu. Il ne se dit alors que de personnes.
>
> C’est presque exclusivement la forme masculine, *quelqu’un*, que l’on
> emploie pour évoquer une personne indéterminée; l’emploi de
> *quelqu’une* est possible, mais rare.
>
> > [...]
> > Ma collègue est **quelqu’un** d’exceptionnel.
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique*, OQLF, « [Le pronom indéfini
> *quelqu'un*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23437/la-grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-indefinis/le-pronom-indefini-quelquun) » ]

---

*Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, 14<sup>e</sup>, éd. Duculot, § 758 b 1, H3) dit « La forme masculine *quelqu'un* est usitée aussi à propos de femmes » et « Le féminin *quelqu'une* n'est toutefois pas sans exemple : [...] — « Mon mari a sûrement trouvé QUELQU'UNE par là, en bas, une ouvrière », disait Ernestine (VAILLAND, *Beau Masque*, II, 3) » puis, en note « *Quelqu'une* nominal féminin. a toujours été sporadique : [...] — *C'est une loi commune / Qui veut que tôt ou tard je coure après QUELQU'UNE (BENSERADE, cit. [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/quelqu%27un)). »

---

Oui, c'est vraiment le cas que comme *nominal* il soit à tout le moins *usité* d'employer le pronom *quelqu'un* au masculin à propos de femmes, mais le féminin du pronom (*quelqu'un*e) reste possible pour les mêmes cas, si on fait ce choix.